# How to echo a property of an object defined in another file

Tags: php, oop, include

I'm starting to learn PHP and OOP and I'm stuck. I have 3 different php 
files that I paste below. The particular problem is stated after the code:

File1.php :

```
<?php
class Page{
    public $intro;
    public $article;

}

$TD = new Page($intro, $article); 


$TD->intro="I'm the intro";
$TD->article="I'm an article";
?>
```

File2.php

```
<?php
function test($page){
switch($page){
    case "A":
        include "file1.php";
        break;
    case "B":
        include "anotherfile.php";
        break;
    }
}
?>
```

File3.php (the one that has to print something):

```
<?php
$page="A";
include "file2.php";

test($page);

echo $TD->intro;
echo $TD->article;
?>
```

I can't echoing (says that $TD is undefined), but I've been testing and it seems that it's effectively loading the file1.php (where the $TD object is defined). Furthermore, if I paste the problematic echoes in the file1.php and loading this page, the echoes work.

I suppose that it's something obvious but I am not capable of figure it out yet.

Thanks in advance for your response and for reading this to the end!!! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your include is in the scope of the function, so the variables that are defined in the include are only visible inside of the function.

```
function test($page){
    switch( $page) {
        case "A":
            include "file1.php";
            // $TD is in scope here, but not outside this scope
        break;
    }
}
```

A quick fix is to add `global $TD;` at the top of your `test()` function.